# Newbie question: Where is my rendered PNG saved to?

Tags: rendering, saving

macOS Mojave 10.14.4

I set /Users/username/Documents/BLENDER/rendering as output **path**.

Is the filename from the .blend files used?

Comment: Image -> Save as Image. Then enter your filename. Output path is for rendering animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you render only a single frame, you have to save your image manually, by going to menu Image > Save as..
The output path is only for rendering animations or video sequences. This is relatively standard in other 3d packages too.

Comment: Vilém, I am new to 3d, so this fact is surprising me. For a good reason: the possibility to explicitly set an output path, is leading (most probably) all new users lightyears away from the idea, images has to be saved in an extra step. - At least I got totally confused by this.